# How to show Dom parser result in android list view

Tags: android, dom, sax

I would like to know how to implement the result of the following code into an android listview.

Thanks in advance

```
package com.androidpeople.xml.parsing;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView name[];
        TextView website[];
        TextView category[];

        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://www.............com//example.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                name[i] = new TextView(this);
                website[i] = new TextView(this);
                category[i] = new TextView(this);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                name[i].setText("Name = "
                        + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                website[i].setText("Website = "
                        + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                category[i].setText("Website Category = "
                        + websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));

                layout.addView(name[i]);
                layout.addView(website[i]);
                layout.addView(category[i]);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }
}
```

Comment: erm.. What do you want to put in a listview? A row with name, website and category for each element you read from the DOM? You need to specify more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: You definitely should move the networking code out of `onCreate()` and into a background thread.

Comment: Hi, could you post your code for display the output as a listview please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> please guide me how i can put this code into android listview

Create a subclass of `BaseAdapter` that wraps around your parsed DOM and returns rows as requested via `getView()`. This is not significantly different than using `ArrayAdapter` for an `ArrayList` or `CursorAdapter` for a `Cursor`, except that you have to do more of the work yourself, since there is no `DOMAdapter` in Android.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .Let c if i can implement in this way. once again thanks

Comment: Hi Kread it can be any element like name . Ignoring the other elements , Actually i have found that reading the xml file from the server is very efficient while using Dom . and now  am making the website which will contain the information about the context of the user . so i have to show that view on the android so i am confused how to show Dom information in a list view if it contains the picture information as well . thanks for your concern